# How to bind multiple values with same Id into single array in angular

Tags: angular

I've this array

```
Products = [
0 : {category_Id : 12 , ProductId : 11, Product name : "Salwar"}
1 : {category_Id : 12 , ProductId : 12, Product name : "Saree"}
2 : {category_Id : 12 , ProductId : 13, Product name : "Dress"}
3 : {category_Id : 13 , ProductId : 14, Product name : "Sandals"}
4 : {category_Id : 13 , ProductId : 15, Product name : "Wedges"}]
```

I'm trying to bind products with same category Id into single array index
for eg:

```
 category[12] : [{ProductId : 11, Product name : "Salwar"},{ProductId : 12, Product name : "Saree"},{ProductId : 13, Product name : "Dress"}] 

 category[13] : [{ProductId : 14, Product name : "Sandals"},{ProductId : 15, Product name : "Wedges"}]
```

If I want to print products with category Id 13, Both Sandals and Wedges should be printed.
Any ideas on how to get that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter` for that:

```js
products = [
  {category_Id : 12 , ProductId : 11, Product_name : "Salwar"},
  {category_Id : 12 , ProductId : 12, Product_name : "Saree"},
  {category_Id : 12 , ProductId : 13, Product_name : "Dress"},
  {category_Id : 13 , ProductId : 14, Product_name : "Sandals"},
  {category_Id : 13 , ProductId : 15, Product_name : "Wedges"}
];

getCategory(id){
  return products.filter(p=>p.category_Id==id);
}

console.log(getCategory(12));
console.log('*************');
console.log(getCategory(13));
```

Comment: Asaf, in angular we write `getCategory(id){...}` without the word `function`

Comment: Oh, I didnt saw this question is for angular, seems to me like a js question

Answer (score 1):

first filter equal identities, then map each item for desired outcome

```
const category = (Products || [])
    .filter(product => product.ProductId === product.category_Id)
    .map(product => ({ ProductId: product.ProductId, "Product name": product["Product name"] }))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.